# malloc unable to allocate memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, allocation

i just don't get why malloc keeps failing with "Cannot allocate memory" in this function: (it triggers the perror and return -1)

EDIT: size_t is an unsigned type, of course it won't work when passing -1

```
int circularBuffer_get(circularBuffer_t *buf, size_t count, void ***retArray) { 
    size_t retVal = (count >= 0 ? count : buf->elCount);
    if (retVal == 0) return 0;

    /* ALloco l'array di ritorno */
    void **retArr = malloc(sizeof(void*) * retVal);
    if(!retArr) {perror("Allocating return value"); return -1; }
    memset(retArr, 0, sizeof(void*) * retVal);

    int i, j = 0; /* Percorro gli elementi da estrarre */
    for (i = (buf->bufCursor - retVal + buf->bufSize) % buf->bufSize; i < retVal; i = (i+1) % buf->bufSize ) {
        /* Estraggo l'elemento */
        retArr[j] = buf->buffer[i];

        /* Libero lo slot nel buffer */
        buf->buffer[i] = NULL;
        j++;
    }

    /* Aggiorno il numero di elementi nel buffer */
    buf->elCount -= retVal;

    *retArray = retArr;
    return retVal;
}
```

i am calling that function at the main function as:

```
circularBuffer_get(buf, -1, (void***)&arr);
```

notice that buf is allocated fine (i checked each value and pointer and the current value of buf->elCount is 1 (i checked that using a printf, too).

I don't think that's a problem with the virtual machine i'm using, either, as other programs run just fine allocating stuff...

Comment: For starters this statement size_t retVal = (count >= 0 ? count : buf->elCount); does not make sense.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type. So `-1` becomes a huge value when assigned to a `size_t`.

Comment: oh god that's right
why am i so dumb?

Comment: also @VladfromMoscow it's a sizeof(void*), which has sense

Comment: @NokiStrawby  I advice to delete the question update your code and ask the question with the  new  updated code.

Comment: @NokiStrawby I did not see that there is a pointer.:)

Comment: the error was that size_t is an unsigned type, those two "errors" you pointed out aren't actually errors... i'm pretty sure about that

Comment: There is `ssize_t` on POSIX systems which might be what you want to use as type for the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type size_t i used is unsigned, and passing a -1 as an argument will lead to such errors

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t(-1) = 18446744073709551615
```

You might have just run out of memory :)